# Problem with Tensorflow lite conversion with dilation_rate !=1

Tags: interpreter, tensorflow-lite

I have the problem when importing the Tensorflow lite-model (last line code below) tf.lite.Interpreter, i get an error (see below) when the dilation_rate!=1. Since the code has to run on a embedded device, hence there will be many steps after this piece of code, the shortest way to get it work, would be a work-around. Does anyone know a work-around to get this functionality working?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\training\tflite_test.py", line 16, in <module>
    interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter( model_content=tflite_model )
  File "D:\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\interpreter.py", line 224, in __init__custom_op_registerers_by_func))
ValueError: tensorflow/lite/core/subgraph.cc BytesRequired number of elements overflowed.
Tensor 22 is invalidly specified in schema.
# Tensorflow 2.4.1
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D( 9, 7, dilation_rate=1, padding="causal", activation='relu', input_shape=(10,20) ), 
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D( 6, 7, dilation_rate=2, padding="causal", activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense( 12, activation='relu', name='hidden'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense( 1, activation='sigmoid', name='output' )
    ])
model.save( "tflite_test_model" )
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model( "tflite_test_model" )
tflite_model = converter.convert()
interpreter = tf.lite.Interpreter( model_content=tflite_model )***
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The recent TF versions including TF 2.5 rc version and TF nightly version have a fix for supporting dilation rate != 1 in the TFLite conversion. Please try out your code at the recent TF versions.

Comment: Many thanks, i installed the unstable version 2.5.0-rc2 and resolves this error. I hope that due to this unstable version i don't run into other issues.

Comment: TF 2.5 stable version will be released after the some moment. You can easily switch to that later.

Comment: I have a strange phenomenon now. With TF 2.5 the conversion in Python looks to be good. After importing Tensoflow Lite model in Python and making inferences everything looks good (accuracy is as expected). But if one looks with Netron to the model the layers with Conv1D and dilation_rate!=1 have the wrong output shape (due to the operator SpaceToBatchNd which is generated internally). Also when importing the model in Tensorflow Lite Micro (in Arduino), the initialization fails due to the wrong shape. So my initial problem is solved now, but overall i still have a problem.

Comment: Please post another issue regarding the shapes to keep each post focused.

Comment: The tf-nightly version has been improved to support the case where dilation_rate != 1. Please try out the tf-nightly version as well.